# Login successful but not redirect to another page in reactjs (react-router-dom, axios)

Tags: node.js, reactjs

As the title, when I log in successfully it will remain on the login page. It worked before, but now it doesn't. I thought the error was because I used loadToken () (the route as shown below) but it wasn't. Someone please point out my mistake and help me fix it.
I'm a newbie

```
//logRegRequester.js
    login = async () => {
        const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/logRegRequester', {
            logemail: this.state.logemail,
            logpassword: this.state.logpassword
        })
        console.log(res);
        if (res.status === 200) {
            saveToken(res.data.userId);
            this.props.history.push('/homeRequester');
        }
    }

//server
if (req.body.logemail && req.body.logpassword) {
    User.authenticate(req.body.logemail, req.body.logpassword, function (error, user) {
      if (error || !user) {
        var err = new Error('Wrong email or password.');
        err.status = 401;
        return next(err);
      } else {
        req.session.userId = user._id;
        return res.send({userId: user._id});
      }
    });
  }

//app.js
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Route path="/" exact component={home} />
        <Route path="/logRegRequester" exact component={logReg} />
        <Route path="/homeRequester" exact component={homeRequester} />
        {/* {loadToken() ? <Route path="/homeRequester" exact component={homeRequester} /> : <Redirectto="/" />} */}
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Put a console and check whether your code reached to this line `this.props.history.push('/homeRequester');`

Comment: It was successful before, but it is not now. It looks like it redirects to ```localhost:3000/logRegRequester?email = ... &password = ...``` (in the url bar). In the console, I do not receive anything returned. Although it previously returned an object as expected when I was still logged in successfully. I can't understand what has changed is that it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: In your previous working copy the loadToken line was commented out as like your current code?

Comment: No, before that, it is not commented, nor is there a 3rd Route (as the code above). But it still doesn't work when I fix it like that

Comment: can you please post it into codepen or any sandbox?